# C# deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a question about deserialization.
It's a part of xml file

```
<N Name="MyName">Number of MyName</N>
```

and class in c#:

```
MyN
{
  [XmlAttribute(AttrName='Name')]
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public string Number {get;set}
}
```

I want to  make that value of N in xml file (in samle - "Number of MyName") will deserialze in property Number of MyN class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [XmlText()] Attribute

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="N")]
MyN
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttrName='Name')]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [XmlText()]
    public string Number {get;set}
}
```

Check this for more information about Xml Serialization in C#
http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173

Comment: Don't forget about `[XmlRoot(ElementName="N")]` for the `MyN` class

Comment: Thank you. It works. But there were some problems with array serialization. XmlArrayItem and XmlArray attributes solve it.

Answer (score 3):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="N")]
public class MyN
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This will assume that you have `<N Name="MyName"><Number>Number of MyName</Number></N>`

Answer (score 0):

```
MyN
{
  [XmlAttribute(AttrName='Name')]
  public string Name {get;set;}

  [XmlText]
  public string Number {get;set}
}
```